# How to set select2 to a specific value?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I have a website. There you can either go manually to a specific site, or go there by using a dropdown menu (select2).
If I go there manually (link), I want to change the value in the dropdown to the sites one.

Here is my select2 code:

```
$(function () {
  $("#siteSelect").select2().on("select2:select", function (e) {
   $("#siteSelect").val(-1).trigger("change");
        var id = $(this).val();
        var url = siteRoot + "/site/site?siteID=" + id ;
        $("#Container").load(url);
    });
});
```

Can you give me some hints how to do that?

I tried to set the value by:
    $("#siteSelect").val(siteName);

Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#siteSelect").select2().select2('val','your value');
```

Comment: I can't replace ("#Container"), cause it's a partial view that will be loaded.

Comment: Updated the ans, check once

Comment: thanks, that kind of worked me. Doesn't show me the name, but it shows the value,that matters the most!

Answer (score 1):

The select2 objects are not able to detect changes and the require you to do that manually as of now. The way to do that is as follows.

```
  $("#siteSelect").val('<your value>');
    $("#siteSelect").trigger('change');
```

The `.trigger()` call on an object lets select2 know of any changes it needs to be aware of. Unfortunately this is the only solution for v4.0.0 unless a newer version fixes this issue.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Have made the appropriate changes.